# how do i fix the constraint is not convex problem?

Tags: cplex

I trying to solve mixed-integer linear programming with CPLEX 12.10 OPL.
I have coded this case about MRP and met this error : Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  5002: 'ct5#0#0#0' is not convex.->.
this is my code:

```
    // INDEX
 int I=...;
 int R =...;
 int T=...;
 range items = 1..I;            //Index of items in the production system i
 range resources = 1..R;        //Index of production resources defining capacity r
 range times = 1..T;            //Index of discrete periods in the planning horizon t
 range trucks = 1..3;               //Index of item j according to the bill of materials
 // DATA & PARAMATER
 int  lamda=...;
 float d[items][times]=...;     //Independent (external) demand for item i in period t
 float b[items][trucks]=...;            //Number of units of item i required per unit of item j according to the bill of materials
 int tau[items]=...;            //Time to process or purchase a lot of the product i
 float f[items][resources]=...; //Fraction of resource r required to process a unit of item i
 float w[items][resources]=...; //Fraction of resource r required to set up a unit of item i
 float ma[resources][times]=...;//Maximum fraction of resourcer that can be added in period t
 float e[items]=...;            //Inventory accuracy of item i
 float l[items]=...;            //Minimum production lot size for item i
 float ac[resources][times]=...;//Cost per added capacity fraction to resource r in period t
 float wc[items]=...;           //Total fixed cost of setting up the production/purchase of item i in a period
 float sc[items]=...;           //Inventory holding cost per period for one unit of item i
 float s0[items]=...;           //Initial on-hand inventory for item i
 int    h[items]=...;               // Maximum slack for production or purchase time
 float g[items][resources]=...;         // Maximum tolerance of capacity for manufacturing
 float n[items]=...;                // Tolerance for inventory accuracy
 //DECISION VARIABLES
 dvar int+ p[items][times];     //Production quantity of item i in period t
 dvar int+ S[items][times];     //Final inventory of item i in period t
 dvar int+ a[resources][times]; //Added fraction of resource r in period t
 dvar float+ q[items][times];       //Binary production indicator for product i in period t
 // Auxiliary variable
dvar float+ sreal[items][times];
dvar float+ delta_plus[items][times];
dvar float+ delta_minus[items][times];
 // OBLJECTIVE FUNCTION
 minimize   sum(t in times) (sum(r in resources) a[r][t]*ac[r][t] + sum( i in items) (q[i][t]*wc[i] + e[i]*S[i][t]*sc[i]))  ;
// Flow constraint
subject to {
 
 forall(t in times, r in resources)
   ct1:sum (i in items)(p[i][t]*f[i][r] + q[i][t]*w[i][r]) <= 1 + a[r][t]  ;  //(1)
 forall (i in items, t in times:(t-tau[i]) in times)
   ct2:sum (j in trucks) p[i][t]*b[i][j] + d[i][t] + e[i]*S[i][t] - e[i]*S[i][t-1] - p[i][t-tau[i]] <= 1; //(2)
 forall (r in resources, t in times)
   ct3:a[r][t] <= ma[r][t]; //(3)
 forall (i in items, t in times)
   ct4:p[i][t] >= q[i][t]*l[i]; //(4)
forall(i in items, t in times, r in resources)
  ct5: p[i][t] * (f[i][r] + (10 - lamda) * q[i][t] * g[i][r]) + q[i][t] * w[i][r] <= a[r][t] + 1;
 forall(i in items, t in times:(t - (tau[i] + (10 - lamda) * h[i])) in times)
    ct6:p[i][t - (tau[i] + (10 - lamda) * h[i])] + ((e[i] + n[i] * (10 - lamda)) * (S[i][t - 1] - S[i][t])) - sum(j in trucks) (p[i][t] * b[i][j]) + delta_plus[i][t] - delta_minus[i][t] <= d[i][t]; //(6)
  forall(i in items, t in times:(t - (tau[i] + (10 - lamda) * h[i])) in times)
    ct7:p[i][t - (tau[i] + (10 - lamda) * h[i])] + ((e[i] - n[i] * (10 - lamda)) * (S[i][t - 1] - S[i][t])) - sum(j in trucks) (p[i][t] * b[i][j]) - delta_plus[i][t] + delta_minus[i][t] >= d[i][t];  //(7) 
 forall(i in items, t in times)
    ct8:(e[i] + n[i] * (10 - lamda)) * S[i][t] <= sreal[i][t]; //(8)
  forall(i in items, t in times)
    ct9:(e[i] - n[i] * (10 - lamda)) * S[i][t] >= sreal[i][t];  //(9)
 }
```

this is my dat code:

```
SheetConnection excelsheet("CAPSTONE-DATA (4).xlsx");
 
 I=6;
 R=4;
 T=12;
 lamda=8;
 d from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet1!B2:M7");
 b from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet2!B2:D7");
 tau from SheetRead(excelsheet,"Sheet3!B2:B7");
 f from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet4!B2:E7");
 w from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet5!B2:E7");
 ma from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet6!B2:M5");
 e from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet7!B2:B7");
 l from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet8!B2:B7");
 ac from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet9!B2:M5");
 wc from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet10!B2:B7");
 sc from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet11!B2:B7");
 s0 from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet12!B2:B7");
 h from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet13!B2:B7");
 g from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet14!B2:E7");
 n from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet15!B2:B7");
```

and this is my data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uovMLPD18KLomkgZPQR0AxtD8pEQBoTX/edit#gid=1564457780

please help me